# C++ Qt window positioning

Tags: c++, qt, window, tooltip

Does Qt has something to offer for the positioning of the tooltip-like windows? (or any types of windows/widgets actually).

I want to be able to update the position of the window automatically, so that it **always stays on the screen** (or at least fits it as much as possible).

An example of the behaviour I want can be seen in the standard Windows tooltips in the notification area. If the tooltip is big and it has some part of it *going off the screen*, it gets automatically repositioned.

Obviously, I can write the code myself, but I'm looking for something that has already been written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if Qt has one single function that ensures a widget is totally inside of the screen. But with [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry-2) it's probably trivial to do.

```
void function RestrainWidgetToScreen(QWidget * w)
{
    QRect screenRect = QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry(w);
    if(w->frameGeometry().left() < screenRect.left()) {
        w->move(screenRect.left() - w->frameGeometry().left(), 0);
    } else if(w->frameGeometry().right() > screenRect.right()) {
        w->move(screenRect.right() - w->frameGeometry().right(), 0);
    }
    if(w->frameGeometry().top() < screenRect.top()) {
        w->move(0, screenRect.top() - w->frameGeometry().top());
    } else if(w->frameGeometry().bottom() < screenRect.bottom()) {
        w->move(0, screenRect.bottom() - w->frameGeometry().bottom());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, I didn't know about `::availableGeometry` method.